# How to add or remove EditText with button

Tags: java, android

Im new in programing especially in java and Android studio.

I want to create activity where you can add or remove EditText with button. When all data is entered I want to calculate something by pressing calculate button and pass value to the next activity. I am attaching a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFOgv.png) of how it should look like. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can `setVisibility` of the `EditText` to hide and show.

**Try the following code:**

```
Button btn=findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

And if you want to sent data from one activity to another you can send it through `Intent`.

```
Intent i=new Intent(this,SomeActivity.class);
i.putExtra("key","somevalue");
startActivity(i);
```

You can get value by `getIntent()` in the next actcivity.

```
String key=getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

Comment: Maybe I should mention that I want too add or remove `EditText`  in runtime. Thanks for the `Intent` tho, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look how to make a calculator first. You need to define operators (`+,-,/,*`) which will allow you to calculate. I can provide you a very good article called [Simple Calculator App in Android Studio for Beginners](https://medium.com/swlh/simple-calculator-app-in-android-studio-for-beginners-d0324ef10420) that will show you how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

To add a view use `addView()` method and to remove a view use `removeView()`. For example I'm using `ConstraintLayout` here , you can try on others layout also.

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:text="add"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/remove"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/remove" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/remove"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="144dp"
        android:text="remove"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity-

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button add, remove;
    private EditText editText;
    private String editTextName;
    private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    private TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        remove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final EditText edittext = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                alertdialog.setMessage("Input a Name");
                alertdialog.setTitle("Add New Item");
                alertdialog.setView(edittext);

                alertdialog.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        editTextName = edittext.getText().toString();
                        constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
                        textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        textView.setText(editTextName);
                        constraintLayout.addView(textView);


                        editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                        constraintLayout.addView(editText);

                    }
                });

                alertdialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // TODO
                    }
                });

                alertdialog.show();
            }
        });
        remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (editTextName != null) {
                    constraintLayout.removeView(editText);
                    constraintLayout.removeView(textView);

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you want run time layout design , please keep eye on `layoutparams`  .